# VBA - Why isn't a gradient bar showing for a specific value?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Why isn't there a gradient for 10% below?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figured this one by myself. I should have selected "Number" for the type dropdown in the rule above. Then, Minimum = 0 and maximum = 1. That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Because your results range from `10%` (a.k.a. `0.1`) to `100%` (a.k.a.`1`)

As such, `0%` of your **data range** is a *value* of `0.1`, `100%` of your **data range** is a *value* of `1`, and `50%` of your **data range** is a *value* of `0.55`

The easiest way to verify this would be to change your top value from `1` to either `1.5` (`150%`) or `0.5` (`50%`), and observe the rest of the bars change.

Try "Type" from "Percentage" to "Number", and have your range from `0` to `1` instead